# Decimal Format null handling

Tags: java

I am using Java 1.6  and we are using `java.text.DecimalFormat` to format numbers. For example

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    df.setPositivePrefix("$");
    df.setNegativePrefix("(".concat($));
    df.setNegativeSuffix(")");
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    df.setGroupingSize(3);

    df.format(new java.math.BigDecimal(100);
```

My application crash whenever pass `null` value to  `df.format(null)`

```
Error: cannot format given object as a number
```

My question is, how can I handle `null` value in `df.format()` function ?

I would like to pass null to `df.format()` function and would want it to return `0.00` instead of above error.

Thanks You

Regards,

Ankush

Comment: This isn't clear; where in your above code are you passing `null` to `df.format`?

Comment: use turnery operator to check null condition of value like value != null ? value : 0.00

Comment: @Oli , df.format(Value_to_be_formatted) is getting called from JasperReports (not in the scene, here) . I wanted to change format() method to accept null values and return 0 in case of null input.

Answer (score 11):

> My application crash whenever pass null value to

Yes, it would. That's the [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#format%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition%29) behaviour:

> **Throws:** `IllegalArgumentException` - if `number` is `null` or not an instance of `Number`.

Next:

> I would like to pass null to df.format() function and would want it to return 0.00 instead of above error.

No, that's not going to work. It's documented not to work. Just don't pass `null` in... it's easy enough to detect. So you could use this:

```
String text = value == null ? "0.00" : df.format(value);
```

Or

```
String text = df.format(value == null ? BigDecimal.ZERO : value);
```

Comment: df.format(value == null ? BigDecimal.ZERO : value);

This is exactly what we are doing right now  . I was wandering if we could overload format function to accept null and return zero .

Comment: @AnkushChhabra: No. I mean, you *could* extend `DecimalFormat` yourself, override `format` and break the existing contract, but that would be a really bad idea. Just put this in some static helper method, and you should be fine.

Comment: @John Extending is not the only option to overload a function that is introduced by a parent class, as you can see in my answer.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke: Um, my answer doesn't talk about extending `DecimalFormat` at all, nor overloading, nor overriding...

Comment: @John: I'm talking about your comment in answer of Ankushs question to overload the format function

Comment: @TobiasLiefke: Ah, right. Again, no overloading involved - overriding and overloading are very different, and it's worth being careful how you use those terms. But I don't think it's a good idea to extend `Format` either... I'd just use a helper method, rather than change the behaviour of the format itself.

Comment: I wouldn't say that I _change the behavior_ of the format, as I just offer another option to format values. `Format` doesn't require a value to be not null, only `DecimalFormat` does. Imagine that you've got to write some kind of text export. You've got a `Format` for every input attribute, of arbitrary type, that creates the appropriate output text. And some of your attributes are optional. In that case you can't just check for null and return "0.00", as the text for the null value would depend on your attribute. And in that (not hypothetic) scenario my formatter would be the best solution.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke: I think we'll have to agree to differ at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Extending DecimalFormat would break its API (correctly pointed out by Jon Skeet), but you could implement your own Format that wraps the given DecimalFormat:

```
public class OptionalValueFormat extends Format {

  private Format wrappedFormat;

  private String nullValue;

  public OptionalValueFormat(Format wrappedFormat, String nullValue) {
    this.wrappedFormat = wrappedFormat;
    this.nullValue = nullValue;
  }

  @Override
  public StringBuffer format(Object obj, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
    if (obj == null) {
      // Just add our representation of the null value
      return toAppendTo.append(nullValue);
    }

    // Let the default format do its job
    return wrappedFormat.format(obj, toAppendTo, pos);
  }

  @Override
  public Object parseObject(String source, ParsePosition pos) {
    if (source == null || nullValue.equals(source)) {
      // Unwrap null
      return null;
    }

    // Let the default parser do its job
    return wrappedFormat.parseObject(source, pos);
  }

}
```

This wouldn't break the API of `java.text.Format`, as that one only requires `toAppendTo` and `pos` to be not null.

Example for the usage of `OptionalValueFormat`:

```
DecimalFormat df = ...

OptionalValueFormat format = new OptionalValueFormat(df, "0.00");
System.out.println(format.format(new java.math.BigDecimal(100)));
System.out.println(format.format(null));
```

Result:

```
100
0.00
```

Unfortunately none of the helper libraries I know offer such a format wrapper, so you will have to add this class to your project.